# Decoding ASN.1 X2AP messages - How to configure partial decoding in Nokalva ASN.1 compiler?

Tags: decoding, asn.1

I'm using Nokalva ASN.1/C++ 6.7 compiler, and I need to set 'partial decoding' to decode some X2AP PER messages that are quite long and to extract just some field values. I'm using ASN.1 x2ap_15.3.asn specification.

To set 'partial decoding' I need to use the OSS.DataCallback directive: 
----
but I don't know how to define the 'absoluteReference'
Can somebody with experience in Nokalva ASN.1/C++ 6.7 compiler please help me defining 'absoluteReference'?

This is, for example, a json representation of a Handover Request message, and I would be interested in decoding just the fields 'UE-X2AP-ID', 'Cause' and 'GUMMEI'.

```
value1 X2AP-PDU ::= initiatingMessage : {
  procedureCode 0,
  criticality reject,
  value HandoverRequest : {
    protocolIEs {
     {
    id 10,
    criticality reject,
    value UE-X2AP-ID : 1
  },
  {
    id 5,
    criticality ignore,
    value Cause : misc : control-processing-overload
  },
  {
    id 11,
    criticality reject,
    value ECGI : {
      pLMN-Identity '123456'H,
      eUTRANcellIdentifier '0000000000000000000011111111'B
    }
  },
  {
    id 23,
    criticality reject,
    value GUMMEI : {
      gU-Group-ID {
        pLMN-Identity '123456'H,
        mME-Group-ID '1234'H
      },
      mME-Code '11'H
    }
  }
   ...
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about a particular commercial vendor's ASN.1 Tool which is better sent directly to the vendor's support email address.  Please direct your question to support@oss.com instead of using this forum.